# Maven how to unzip more than one file in same directory?

Tags: maven

I have more than one zip file in my folder. I want to unzip all of these files and put into destination folder. I want to avoid specifying each zip file in my pom.xml file. Please check the plugin I wrote. Isn't there any better solution which accepts *.zip files? Thanks a lot.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.7</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>prepare</id>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <configuration>
                <tasks>
                    <unzip src="${user.home}/${dasmo.storage}/calendar-persistence.zip" dest="${user.home}/${dasmo.storage}/" />
                    <unzip src="${user.home}/${dasmo.storage}/controls-persistence.zip" dest="${user.home}/${dasmo.storage}/" />
                    <unzip src="${user.home}/${dasmo.storage}/devices-persistence.zip" dest="${user.home}/${dasmo.storage}/" />
                    <unzip src="${user.home}/${dasmo.storage}/events-persistence.zip" dest="${user.home}/${dasmo.storage}/" />
                    <unzip src="${user.home}/${dasmo.storage}/logs-persistence.zip" dest="${user.home}/${dasmo.storage}/" />
                    <unzip src="${user.home}/${dasmo.storage}/places-persistence.zip" dest="${user.home}/${dasmo.storage}/" />
                    <unzip src="${user.home}/${dasmo.storage}/provisioning-persistence.zip" dest="${user.home}/${dasmo.storage}/" />
                    <unzip src="${user.home}/${dasmo.storage}/recordings-persistence.zip" dest="${user.home}/${dasmo.storage}/" />
                    <unzip src="${user.home}/${dasmo.storage}/scripts-persistence.zip" dest="${user.home}/${dasmo.storage}/" />
                    <unzip src="${user.home}/${dasmo.storage}/smartcontrols-persistence.zip" dest="${user.home}/${dasmo.storage}/" />
                    <unzip src="${user.home}/${dasmo.storage}/storage-persistence.zip" dest="${user.home}/${dasmo.storage}/" />
                    <unzip src="${user.home}/${dasmo.storage}/system-persistence.zip" dest="${user.home}/${dasmo.storage}/" />
                    <unzip src="${user.home}/${dasmo.storage}/webrtc-persistence.zip" dest="${user.home}/${dasmo.storage}/" />

                    <!--  
                    <unzip src="${user.home}/${dasmo.storage}/calendar-persistence.zip" dest="${user.home}/${dasmo.storage}/" />

                    <copy file="${basedir}/../gwr-devices-module/${config.location}" todir="${project.build.directory}/${dasmo.storage}/devices/" />
                    <copy file="${basedir}/../gwr-logs-module/${config.location}" todir="${project.build.directory}/${dasmo.storage}/logs/" />

                    <copy file="${basedir}/../gwr-logs-module/src/main/resources/*.zip" todir="${user.home}/${dasmo.storage}/" />
                    <unzip src="${user.home}/${dasmo.storage}/*.zip" dest="${user.home}/${dasmo.storage}/" />
                    -->
                </tasks>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score -1):

- I'd use [GMavenPlus](https://web.archive.org/web/20150517031225/http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GMAVENPLUS/Examples#Examples-ExecuteScripts) like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30678775/1744774) and
- create code in the `<script>` section inspired by [The Java™ Tutorials , Walking the File Tree](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/walk.html) and [Unzip « File « Java Tutorial](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0180__File/Unzip.htm).

Example:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
      <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.5</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>unzip-files-in-folder</id>
          <phase>process-resources</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>execute</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <scripts>
              <script>
                // ... your unzip code goes here ...
              </script>
            </scripts>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
      </executions>

      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
          <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
          <version>2.4.3</version>
          <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables AFAIK SO isn't intended to supply askers with code out of nothing. Instead of giving the OP a crucial hint where to start he has _nothing_ with your deletion of this answer. And most probably the SO and the Java Tutorials links aren't going to be changed ever. However, I added some example code to comply your will.